# How to remove all booleans (across all layers) from being displayed?

Tags: modifiers

I have many layers with many objects with many booleans. Is there a way I can "un-display" all of them in the viewport?

[image]

Essentially, I'd like all boolean modifiers (across all objects and layers) to have the "eye" icon un-clicked.

Comment: Does any of the shapes have any other modifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way but a small python script can do what you want.

```
import bpy

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    for m in o.modifiers:
        if m.type == 'BOOLEAN':
            m.show_viewport = False
```

You just need to paste this into blender's [text editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/text_editor.html) and click the run script button. You can change the last line from `False` to `True` to turn them all on again.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the modifiers from one object. Select all the other objects you want to remove the modifiers from, making sure you select the object with no modifiers last. Press ctrl + L and select Modifiers.

All the modfiers will be cleared from every object you selected.

Comment: Sweet. Will this REMOVE modifiers? Or just hide them from being displayed in the viewport?

Comment: Sorry didn't read the questions right.  If you only want to hide the modifier, just hide it instead of removing it on the first object.